# (iOS) How to animate rounded rectangle with shapeLayer?

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, shapes, cashapelayer

I am trying to animate the width of a rounded rectangle, the problem is when going from bigger width to thinner width, the animation does an "aberration ease jump".

Here's the code:

```
shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 200.0f);
[shapeLayer setBounds:shapeRect];
[shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(iniPosX, 80.0f)];
[shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setLineWidth:1.0f];
[shapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
[shapeLayer setOpacity:0.2];
path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:shapeRect cornerRadius:15.0];
[shapeLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

And when I start the animation:

```
- (void)adjustSelectorToPosAndSize:(float)posX andWidth:(float)width
{
    shapeRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, 200.0f);
    [shapeLayer setBounds:shapeRect];
    [shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(posX, 80.0f)];
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:shapeRect cornerRadius:15.0];
    [shapeLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the correction Alexis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this with a CAShapeLayer seems overly complicated to me if you are only using it for a rounded rectangle. Why not simply use a CALayer with [the `cornerRadius` properly](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/cornerRadius) set?

Animating the frame with cornerRadius set will work fine.

```
myLayer = [CALayer layer];
shapeRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 200.0f);
[myLayer setBounds:shapeRect];
[myLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(iniPosX, 80.0f)];
[myLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[myLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[myLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[myLayer setOpacity:0.2];
[myLayer setCornerRadius:15.0];
[self.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```

Animating it is done by simply chaining the frame (not the path)

```
- (void)adjustSelectorToPosAndSize:(float)posX andWidth:(float)width
{
    shapeRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, 200.0f);
    [myLayer setBounds:shapeRect];
    [myLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(posX, 80.0f)];
}
```

---

**Important:**

Some of the properties changed name like `fillColor` became `backgroundColor` and the `strokeColor` and `lineWidth` became `borderColor` and `borderWidth` etc.

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't do a animation, is instantaneous.

Comment: I just tried it. It animates using the default 0.3 duration animation. Are you doing anything else with the layer?

Comment: If you want to customize the animation you need to do it explicitly

Comment: Yeah, sorry your code is perfect. I forgot to change "myLayer" CAShapedLayer to CALayer. Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Although CAShapeLayer’s path property is animatable, it does not do so implicitly like bounds and position, you have to make an explicit animation:

```
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
anim.fromValue = (id) fromPath.CGPath;
anim.toValue = (id) toPath.CGPath;
anim.duration = 1.0;
[layer addAnimation: anim forKey: @“resize”];
```

Since you probably want all three animations to happen together, you can make them all explicit and grouped together:

```
CABasicAnimation* anim1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"position"];
anim1.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: fromPosition];
anim1.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: toPosition];
anim1.duration = 1.0;

CABasicAnimation* anim2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"bounds"];
anim2.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect: fromBounds];
anim2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect: toBounds];
anim2.duration = 1.0;

CABasicAnimation* anim3 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
anim3.fromValue = (id) fromPath.CGPath;
anim3.toValue = (id) toPath.CGPath;
anim3.duration = 1.0;

CAAnimationGroup* animG = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animG.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: anim1, anim2, anim3, nil];
animG.duration = 1.0;
[layer addAnimation: animG forKey:@"resize"];
```

If your shape does not have contents or children then you may be able to use a CALayer instead:

```
CALayer* rectLayer = [CALayer layer];
rectLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
rectLayer.bounds = startBounds;
rectLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
rectLayer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
[self.layer addSublayer: rectLayer];

// Then later implicitly animate the bounds:
rectLayer.bounds = newBounds;
```

Comment: Thanks!! I am testing your code, I tell you when you finish testing.

Comment: I'm Sorry, but doesn't work well, I think i'm doing something wrong, but layer doesn't moves to where i want, i think the reference point is different when i do the animation. Sorry my english is not good. The way that you uses the animations, is really of my interest, you opened to me a new way for me in group animations. ^^